# Publishing an R Shiny app to shinyapps.io results in "%PDF-1.5 %"

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am new to R shiny and I seem to have hit a problem that I could not find anywhere online. I made a simple app, but when I publish it to shinyapps.io servers, I get a blank screen with the text "%PDF-1.5 %".

I connected my shinyapps account to my R and it says it has successfully published my app. I have two apps that run exactly as I intend locally, but both give me this blank screen at my shinyapps url.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please provide a minimal reproducible example. The idea is to provide enough of your code that we can help diagnose it, ideally without showing your whole program.